# docker:when i use only --tty or -t (without -i) for the sake of colorful output along with --rm, the docker does not stop on ctrl+c

Tags: docker, tty

Currently i am using docker for development of a django project.

I want to see the output of the commands in color.

I found in this forum `https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-run-with-colorful-output/24542/3` that i have to use `--tty or -t`

So the following is my command

```
hostfolder="/home/web_dev/Docker_django_testing"
dockerfolder="/home/simha/app"
imagename="django_testing"
docker run -t -p 8000:8000 --rm -v ${hostfolder}:${dockerfolder} ${imagename} pipenv run python django_project_test/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I am using `--rm` to stop and remove the container on exit. But because of `-t` the container does not get stopped even after exiting using `Ctrl + c`

Here is the image showing the output of the above command
[image]

And after exiting i checked the output of the `docker ps -a` it shows the container is still running.

```
$ docker ps -a                                    
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
212c039d35ae        django_testing      "pipenv run python d…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   nervous_euclid
```

Where as the same command if i run without `-t` eventhough it does not show up color output, the container gets stopped and removed on exit by using `Ctrl + c`

The below image shows the output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use `-t` without `-i` your stdin is **not** connected to the program's stdin (in this case `pipenv run ...`). This means that when you press *Control C*, this is passed to the `docker run` command and therefore `docker run` exits, but it's **not** passed to the container's main process and therefore the container keeps running. In short, you need the `-i` option too:

```
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 --rm -v ${hostfolder}:${dockerfolder} ${imagename} pipenv run python django_project_test/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```